# What is the alternative for match in react router dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Recently I started upgrading from `react-router-dom v5` to `v6` and I have something in my `Route` which I don't know what it is and what is the alternative in `react-router-dom v6`. The keyword `match` inside `<LayoutReport match={props} />` is giving me warning:

```
(property) match: any
Type '{ match: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'match' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

This is my `Route`

```
<Route
  path="reports/*"
  element={props => (
     <FilterBarProvider>
        <LayoutReport match={props} />
     </FilterBarProvider>)}
/>
```

Comment: What is the typescript declaration for this `LayoutReport` component? The error/warning is informing you it doesn't accept any `match: any` proptype. What are you *really* wanting to ask about here, a replacement for *some* "match" "thing" in `react-router-dom@6`, or the Typescript error/warning about *some* component's `match` prop? What are you really trying to accomplish here? BTW, the `Route` component's `element` prop takes only a `React.ReactNode` value, not a function.

Comment: @DrewReese Hi, `LayoutReport` is not typescript it is `.js`. The `LayoutReport` component is imported into the `Dashboard` component inside `Routes`. And about the `match` in my old code base, it was used with `RRDv5`. Now, I don't have any idea what the use of `match` inside the `LayoutReport` component is.

Comment: What do you need from the old `match` object? What were you using it for?

Comment: @DrewReese what I see on `console.log` `match` is `history`, `location`, and `match`.  I tried using `hooks` as you suggested in the `LayoutReport` component and it is working partially. I used `useNavgiate`, `useLocation`, and `useMatch` hooks.

Comment: There's no RRDv6 replacement for the old RRDv5 route props. What *exactly* where you accessing from the `match` object in the older code?

Comment: @DrewReese Hey, so the `match`  object in the older code was passed from the `props` containing `history`, `location`, and `match`. As `ReportLayout` contains routes to different dashboard layouts. But, I removed the `match={props}` and used hooks to get all of the above three objects. and it is working now. Cheers!

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to explain with my answer below, sorry if it wasn't coming through well enough. I'll edit to make that more clear. Glad it is all working for you now. Cheers.

Comment: @DrewReese yeah, like in your updated answer below, I created `pageProps` object like this `pageProps={history: useNavigation(location.path), location: location, match: useMatch() }` . Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are asking two questions, one about the Typescript error/warning, and the other is an implied "how to access route props in RRDv6" via the title. Answering the second rather resolves the first. In `react-router-dom@6` there are no longer any route props. In fact, the `element` prop takes only a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, not any callback function that may or may not return JSX.

The route should look something like:

```
<Route
  path="reports/*"
  element={(
    <FilterBarProvider>
      <LayoutReport />
   </FilterBarProvider>
  )}
/>
```

This will remove the Typescript error/warning about the `match` prop that was passed.

But now how to access the old RRDv5 `match` object? This is easy, use React hooks to access what was previously provided on the `match` object. For example, if you are trying to access route path params, use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.0/hooks/use-params) hook to access the `params` object, i.e. what *used* to be `match.params`.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const LayoutReport = () => {  // <-- remove undefined `match` prop
  const params = useParams(); // <-- access params via hook

  ...
};
```

There are other hooks to access other route information, so it depends on what you need to access which hook you use.

- `history` object was replaced by a `navigate` function via the `useNavigate` hook
- `location` object via the `useLocation` hook
- `match` object was eliminated, you can access the `params` via the `useParams` hook.

Example:

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const LayoutReport = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();

  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `useParams` hook. https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#useparams

Comment: Did not get exactly how you are implying on using `useParams` in replace of `match={props}`?